# Can't open a second camera

Tags: opencv

How do I open a second camera using OpenCV?  I'm using VS2008, OpenCV 2.4.13, and have 2 different kinds of usb camera attached.

I tried using the code below, but I get the error:

> Capture1 can't be opened

The code is:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    if( !capture.isOpened() )
        std::cout << "Capture0 can't be opened\n" << std::endl;

    VideoCapture capture1(1);
    if( !capture1.isOpened() )
        std::cout << "Capture1 can't be opened\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should use grab() then retrieve() when using multiple camera http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab

Comment: you can check my experienced-based answer below :) hope it help.

Comment: what about VideoCapture capture1(DSHOW +1)?

Comment: It is still has the wrong result. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can iterate through 0 to 100 to check if OpenCV index the device consecutive or not (normally it consecutive). Then you can try ffmpeg to open camera (OpenCV use ffmpeg underlying to manage Video I/O). Then update your question.

Comment: @khôi nguyễn  Thank you, i have found that these camera use the same usb controller.If I want to open these cameras, i have to decrease the resolution. Below is the code that i can open the two camera:`int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    VideoCapture camera0(1);
    camera0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,432);
    camera0.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);
    VideoCapture camera1(0);
    camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,432);
    camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced some old camera that take several seconds waiting for ready to capture. If you capture at that "waiting ready" time it will return an empty (OpenCV) or black image (DirectShow). It happens even in single camera. You can trap in while (img.empty()) loop until it properly return an valid image and measure how long this period is.

In multiple camera environment, to make all camera ready for capture, you could grab then retrieve.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab

Comment: @Jack_Wellem it is opened doesn't mean it's ready for capturing :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But now i find that I can't open the second cammera when using the following code. 

`int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture capture(0);
    if( !capture.isOpened() )
        std::cout << "Capture0 can't be opened\n" << std::endl;

    VideoCapture capture1(1);
    if( !capture1.isOpened() )
        std::cout << "Capture1 can't be opened\n" << std::endl;

 return 0;
}`

Comment: @Jack_Wellem please update your question for clearer view.

Comment: I am sorry for the  question which is asked before, now the question is updated.